# How to initialize an empty array of constraints related to a model in JuMP?

Tags: arrays, julia, constraints, mathematical-optimization, julia-jump

In my algorithm, I add 3 different sets of constraints dynamically to a model (`m1`), which then I keep in 3 `ConstraintRef[]` arrays (namely `a,b,c`). The number of constraints added differ from iteration to iteration.
I also need to access the dual values of these constraints after solving it, which for this model is not a problem (for example, `dual.(a)`).
However, at some point in my algorithm, I need to solve a copy of my model (`m2`). After solving it, I cannot query the duals, since the arrays `a,b,c` do not have any information about `m2`.

Is there a way of linking/registering the array names to the model, so that when the model is copied, I can access the dual values efficiently?

**Update**, here a small example:

```
using JuMP
using GLPK

a = ConstraintRef[]
m1 = Model(GLPK.Optimizer)
@variable(m1,x)
con1 = @constraint(m1, x==2)
push!(a,con1)
optimize!(m1)
d = dual.(a)

# (..) I keep adding constraints to 'a'

m2 = copy(m1)
set_optimizer(m2, GLPK.Optimizer)

# (..) I keep populating the set of constraints in 'a'

optimize!(m2)
```

What I want to be able to do is to get the duals of all constraints included in a, but for `m2`. Obviously, `dual.(a)` does not work. I add the constraints as anonymous because I don't know beforehand how many do I need to add at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to provide help if you provide a minimal working example of what you are trying to achieve.

However, you are probably looking for the `reference_map` that is returned from `copy_model`, which maps between objects in the original model and the copied object in the new model:

```
model = Model()
@variable(model, x)
@constraint(model, cref, x == 2)

new_model, reference_map = copy_model(model)
x_new = reference_map[x]
cref_new = reference_map[cref]
```

Docs: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/dev/reference/models/#JuMP.copy_model

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of the `reference_map` and is not exactly what I am looking for. As you say, I have updated the question description with a small example.

Comment: You need to map each element of the vector: `[dual(reference_map[ai]) for ai in a]`.